# Two components I’m trying to identify

Tags: identify-this-game-piece

I have two components I’m trying to identify.

The first is the card with no. 10 on it.

The second is a crown with numbers on it.

Sorry for the low resolution.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [boardgames.se]! Please [do not delete questions after getting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211145/295232), that is frowned upon here.

Answer (score 2):

They are from Innovation and A Feast for Odin.

You can see the 10 card from Innovation [here](https://www.thegamesteward.com/products/innovation-ultimate-edition-kickstarter-edition-board-game?ID=EN-GB-TGS-TS001556A-BGB-CKGB&utm_source=GoogleAds&utm_campaign=TGSI-UnitedKingdom&utm_term=-c--g&utm_medium=Shopping-GB-en&utm_content=cos:GB-merchantid:114058706-country:GB-language:en-campaignid:948294932-adgroupid:47453460416-network:g-device:c-keyword:-matchtype:-placement:-adposition:&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiApaarBhB7EiwAYiMwqp71TnmD8fuhMx3avzOAPWuF-3XpPXS5jisS_zbQuQRkfVuVSmm4bhoCB-YQAvD_BwE).

You can see the crown in an image of this review of A Feast For Odin [here](https://opinionatedgamers.com/2016/11/28/a-feast-for-odin-game-review-by-chris-wray/).

As you also seem to have cards from Jaipur and Hanabi in the same photograph I hope your not using the internet to cheat at a quiz by getting answers from others!